# table echo by row based on user input

Tags: php, mysql

How to edit a row based on user selection. Suppose user select edit button on reservation id 44. How can we edit based on it?

[this is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAMCN.png)

i use this for edit button

```
<form method="post" action="user_update.php">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit">
            </form>
```

this to send to database

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['edit']))
      { 
        header("location: edit.php");}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want simply redirect php page for edit then use anchor `<a>` tag, replace this

```
 <form method="post" action="user_update.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit">
 </form>
```

To

```
<a href="/edit.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><input type="button" value="Edit"></a>
```

Note : `$id` is id number or reservation number by which can get whole form data to display and then submit to edit

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you could try this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['edit']))
    {
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $link = "edit?id=".$id.".php";
        header("location: ".$link);
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="user_update.php">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply Redirect it using a tag

```
<a href="/edit.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Edit</a>
```

Edit.php

```
 if(isset($_GET[id]))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirection
  you can use like that in your table in edit column. and echo your    reservation id and this id get from your url.

```
 <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Edit</a></td>
```

variable set on the basis of get id in Edit.php.

```
 <?php
          if(isset($_GET['id']))
          { 
              $reservationId = $_GET['id'];
               // here your edit code
          }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button type="button"><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Edit</a><button>
```